# Name 'now' is not defined?

Tags: python, datetime

When I typed in the following code it said that name 'now' is not defined. However, I did `import datetime`?

```
from datetime import datetime
print str(now.month) + "/" + str(now.day) + "/" + str(now.year)
```

(*I have already searched on the web for this but it did not come up with anything related to this*)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You haven't defined `now` variable:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
```

Also, to make a string from a datetime, use [strftime()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

> Return a string representing the date, controlled by an explicit
>   format string.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
'09/15/2013'
```

Comment: @ComputerXplorer You don't have to post two separate comments saying that.... The best thank you is accepting the answer! (which you can do in ten minutes by clicking the green check to the left of this answer)

Comment: @Doorknob Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Just to note it's also possible if you just want the data based on the time now (and not explicitly worry about it), an alternative is to use: `time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`

Answer (score 0):

from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
print now